# bash script commands executed twice

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to run a simple `bash` script that runs through folders named `subj1`, `subj2`, etc. and executes an `awk` script in each folder. The problem is that the `awk` command is executed *twice*, even though it is only listed once in the script. I just started using `bash` and I am not sure I understand what is happening here. Any help is appreciated.

```
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
  cd subj$i
  awk -f ../melt.awk subj$i_*.txt
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: I can't see any reason for it. However, `subj$i_*.txt` should be `subj${i}_*.txt`. Otherwise, it's looking for a variable named `$i_`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Put `set -x` before the loop, so it will display all the commands as they're being executed.

Comment: As an aside, `seq` isn't a POSIX-standard command, so scripts relying on it are needlessly unportable (and also slower, since running it involves spawning a subprocess). `for ((i=1; i<10; i++))` is the terse version using only bash built-in functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscore is a valid identifier character, therefore

```
subj$i_*.txt
```

is interpreted in bash as

```
subj${i_}*.txt
```

Which is not what you want. Separate the `i` from the underscore:

```
subj${i}_*.txt
```

or

```
subj$i\_*.txt
```

BTW, you can probably just call

```
awk -f met.awk subj{1..10}_*.txt
```